# 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'CompletedTask' for C#

Tags: c#, task

I'm following the tutorial at https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/getting_started/intro.html to a tee, and yet I'm getting an error when I try to use

```
return Task.CompletedTask
```

and I get this error

```
'Task' does not contain a definition for 'CompletedTask'
```

I am

```
using System.Threading.Tasks
```

Comment: Are you on .NET 4.6 or above?

Comment: Should be. I got the installer and it said I was.

Comment: What do you mean by "installer"?  This would be a project-level setting in Visual Studio...

Comment: It may not be the default option - you can check in Project > Properties [like this](http://i.imgur.com/009x5bD.png).

Comment: Ah yes, it was set to 4.5.x; changed now, will investigate

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  I've added an answer to compile everything into one place :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Task.CompletedTask` is a static property added in .NET 4.6.  [Here is its source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,66f1c3e3e272f591), and [here is its MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) which shows the minimum framework version.

Just for completeness, here is how you change the .NET Framework version you are using in your project.

[image: Project Properties, Target Framework]

Answer (score 23):

If you are unable to upgrade the .NET Framework version, simply

replace `Task.CompletedTask` with `Task.FromResult(0)`.

Comment: This answer is great, because we usually can't change the Asp .NET version on our company projects.